# How can I monitor a contract for transactions?

Tags: python, web3.py

Here's what I've done so far.

```
import json
import sys

import web3
from web3 import Web3, IPCProvider

ADDRESS = '...' #contract address
PIPE = '\\\\.\\pipe\\geth.ipc'

w3 = Web3(IPCProvider(PIPE))
f = w3.eth.filter({
    'contract_address': ADDRESS,
    'toBlock': "latest"
})
def callback(block_hash):
    sys.stdout.write("New Block: {0}".format(block_hash))
f.watch(callback)
```

however this doesn't seem to monitor just the contract I specify with `contract_address` it seems to monitor all (as if I had done `f = w3.eth.filter('latest')`)

Comment: Where did you see `contract_address` documented?

Comment: I assumed I could use the same arguments that [`construct_event_filter_params`](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/blob/master/web3/utils/filters.py#L18) uses. I couldn't find what arguments I could be using for `LogFilter`.

Answer (score 2):

The fields that you can use for setting up a filter are defined in the [JSON-RPC docs for `eth_newFilter`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_newfilter).

Specifically, the address field is just `address`:

> address: DATA|Array, 20 Bytes - (optional) Contract address or a list of addresses from which logs should originate.

So the filter should be set up with:

```
f = w3.eth.filter({
    'address': ADDRESS,
    'toBlock': "latest"
})
```

Comment: This will work only if the contract has logged one event, and will not be called if no event was logged or if the transaction was reversed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `address` instead of `contract_address`. I've just checked the documentation at http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.filter, but didn't test it.